# Method to set a unique identifier in a UI Table Row, retrievable upon selection

Tags: ios4, object, uitableview

So I have an array of objects of type MyClass, and the following variables are defined:

```
@property (retain) IBOutlet  NSString* productName;
@property (retain) IBOutlet  NSString* brandName;
@property (retain) IBOutlet  NSString* category;
@property (retain) IBOutlet  NSString* productDetails;
@property (retain) IBOutlet  NSString* productPrice;
@property (retain) IBOutlet  NSString* points;
@property (retain) IBOutlet  NSString* image;
```

And ive setup the constructor and everything properly wrt the class MyClass.  In one of my view controllers, I'm creating objects of MyClass, and i can use the product.productName = @"SomeProduct" etc. to set and get properly as well.

Now here's where I'm stuck.  I'm embedding a TableViewController in one of my views which displays the productName as the textLabel property of each Cell.   Users can choose between the products by scrolling through the table.  However, when I select a row, I need a way to access the object the cell originated from in order to populate other information on the right side of the screen (image, and other product info).  Is there a way i can set a hidden Unique ID which would easily identify the object?  I really don't want to select the object based on the textlabel matching product.productName, and I don't think that would work when I scale the application up.  If there's a way to "store" the object itself into the cell, that would be great.  If not, some way of storing a key in the cell would let me build a hash table to get the info i need..

Comment: I realize the detailTextLabel property can store a key, but i have a feeling that this has been done before, and in a better way...

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the following method to set the text label on each of your UITableView cells. In this method you find the appropriate MyClass object and set the textLabel property of the UITableView cell to a property of the MyClass object.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

As long as you are currently using this method to populate your cells you can basically copy the code you use to find the correct MyClass object into the following method, which is activated when a cell is selected:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Instead of setting a property once you find the correct MyClass object, call a method to update the view on the right side of the screen with the correct information.

Have a look at the [UITableView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).